# HTML5 custom video player in JS

Tags: javascript, html5

I have created custom video player based on HTML5 video API and JS.
Please review the JS.

P.S. I couldn't add the video, if you want to check how it works, please add some example video.

Thanks.

```js
(function() {
  'use strict';

  const player = document.querySelector('.player');
  const video = player.querySelector('.viewer');

  const toggleButton = document.querySelector('.toggle');
  const progressBar = document.querySelector('.progress');
  const progressBarFilled = document.querySelector('.progress__filled');

  function togglePlay(e) {
    if(video.paused) {
      video.play();
      toggleButton.textContent = '❚❚';
    } else {
      video.pause();
      toggleButton.textContent = '▶';
    }
  }

  function updateVideoProgress(e) {
    video.currentTime = video.duration * e.offsetX / progressBar.clientWidth;
  }

  function makeFullScreen() {
    if(video.requestFullscreen) {
      video.requestFullscreen();
    } else if(video.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
      video.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    } else if(video.msRequestFullScreen) {
      video.msRequestFullScreen();
    }
  }

  player.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if(e.target.closest('.toggle') || e.target.closest('.viewer')) {
      togglePlay();
    } else if(e.target.closest('.progress')) {
      updateVideoProgress(e);
    } else if(e.target.closest('.fullscreen')) {
      makeFullScreen();
    } else {
      const skipButton = e.target.closest('[data-skip]');
      if(skipButton) {
        video.currentTime += Number(skipButton.dataset.skip);
      }
    }
  }, false);

  player.addEventListener('input', e => {
    const rangeSlider = e.target.closest('.player__slider');
    if(!rangeSlider) return;
    video[rangeSlider.name] = rangeSlider.value;
  }, false);

  video.addEventListener('timeupdate', () => {
    progressBarFilled.style.flexBasis = `${video.currentTime * 1.0 / video.duration * 100}%`;
  }, false);

  progressBar.addEventListener('mouseup', e => {
    updateVideoProgress(e);
  }, false);
})();
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  background: #7A419B;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #7c1599 0%, #921099 48%, #7e4ae8 100%);
  background-size: cover;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.player {
  max-width: 750px;
  border: 5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  position: relative;
  font-size: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

/* This css is only applied when fullscreen is active. */
.player:fullscreen {
  max-width: none;
  width: 100%;
}

.player:-webkit-full-screen {
  max-width: none;
  width: 100%;
}

.player__video {
  width: 100%;
}

.player__button {
  background: none;
  border: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  max-width: 50px;
}

.player__button:focus {
  border-color: #ffc600;
}

.player__slider {
  width: 10px;
  height: 30px;
}

.player__controls {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateY(100%) translateY(-5px);
  transition: all .3s;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.player:hover .player__controls {
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.player:hover .progress {
  height: 15px;
}

.player__controls>* {
  flex: 1;
}

.progress {
  flex: 10;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  transition: height 0.3s;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  cursor: ew-resize;
}

.progress__filled {
  width: 50%;
  background: #ffc600;
  flex: 0;
  flex-basis: 0%;
}

/* unholy css to style input type="range" */

input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8.4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), 0 0 1px rgba(13, 13, 13, 0);
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border-radius: 1.3px;
  border: 0.2px solid rgba(1, 1, 1, 0);
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #ffc600;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin-top: -3.5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

input[type=range]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: #bada55;
}

input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8.4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), 0 0 1px rgba(13, 13, 13, 0);
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 1.3px;
  border: 0.2px solid rgba(1, 1, 1, 0);
}

input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), 0 0 0 rgba(13, 13, 13, 0);
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #ffc600;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.fullscreen {
  background: url(https://i.postimg.cc/dVt8fZSX/fullscreen.png) no-repeat;
  background-position: 20% 45%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>HTML Video Player</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="player">
    <video class="player__video viewer" src="652333414.mp4"></video>

    <div class="player__controls">
      <div class="progress">
        <div class="progress__filled"></div>
      </div>
      <button class="player__button toggle" title="Toggle Play">►</button>
      <input type="range" name="volume" class="player__slider" min="0" max="1" step="0.05" value="1">
      <input type="range" name="playbackRate" class="player__slider" min="0.5" max="2" step="0.1" value="1">
      <button data-skip="-10" class="player__button">« 10s</button>
      <button data-skip="25" class="player__button">25s »</button>
      <button class="player__button fullscreen"></button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```